# RegEx replaceAll but ignore newlines

Tags: regex, string

Looking for some regex help! If this can be done in another way / using another tool - please let me know.

Here's a snippet from my data set (there are ~10million rows in total). Every new sequence starts with a '>'.

**Note: The line numbers are not in the actual textfile**

```
01 >M00707:15:000000000-AEN4L:1:1101:13198:1037_PairEnd_SUB_SUB merged_sample={14.3: 1}; count=1;       2:N:0:1
02 ctcccggaaaaatttgagcctccagagtagcatataaccgacacgttgccgcctgaaaat
03 acattttccaggtcttnnnnnaaannnggaagcgcgcaccgacgagctttnnannacaag
04 tgtggctctagtgctcggtatttgcaactttttaagtannatgnnngtcgnnnnngaggn
05 nnnnnnnnntaaccnnncaccttcaagcaagtctaagttctcgactaatcaaactataaa
06 tccgctacacggacccagatctcccgccncgtgcannttaaagcaagtctacgttattga
07 agatagaaactattatatcgctaaacgtagctctganncacgctcgccttgactccgact
08 ctgtcaatgtctacgaccaattgaggtggaacatgtgcacatgtgtttcagancattgga
09 ggaattccgggaaaataaattgaggcacaancgaacggtgatctnnnnnnnttagattct
10 gccatgttttttggcacgaacacaattgggcaaatactgttgggatgtggatggat
11 >M00707:15:000000000-AEN4L:1:1101:10949:1045_PairEnd_SUB_SUB_CMP merged_sample={13.3: 1}; count=1;       2:N:0:1
12 atgacatattaatgattcagcccacattccttaatataccacatatgacttacttttcta
13 tatcaacnnnnnnntactttccacaggtatatacatactatgtttaatactcattaattt
14 acttgncactatattattacattatatgattaatccacatttctataacatattagactt
15 tcctcaactagatattat(first)tttcgt(first)aattattatgcagttgtatgacatattactgaatca
16 gccaacattccttaataaaccncatacgactactctgttatcgtatgtgttttatggtct
17 tgattcttagtaatgggtatgacatattattgattcagccnnnattgttnannannnnac
18 atnnancttactnntcttnttcaactctaatatactttccacaggtatatacatactatg
19 ttnaat(last)actcattaat(last)ttacttgccaatatatcattnnnntatatgattaatccacattt
20 ctataacatattagactttcctcaactagatattattttcgtaattattatgcag
```

I want to cut out everything between the order of characters "tttcgt" and "actcattaat" (but only in that specific order), then replace it with nothing and preserve everything else in its format (with the line breaks etc).

A big challenge to this is also that i need to find tttcgt and actcattaat even if either of those had a line break in between, ie. goes from the end of one line, line break plus line number plus space, and then continued on the next line. (Thanks for @CBroe for pointing that out)

I wrapped "(first)" around the tttcgt chars - see line number 15

I wrapped "(last)" around the actcattaat chars - see line number 19

So far I've mustered up this thinggy **(?<=tttcgt).*?(?=actcattaat)** - but how can I make my expression ignore newlines?

Comment: Do you need to do this strictly in regex ? Regex isn't that great for cutting out parts in the middle of input.

Comment: I'm currently also trying to do this in python, but I'm not that experienced with string manipulation. Its hard to define the correct rule to only cut out the text between the two order of characters..

Comment: First of all, do you need to find `tttcgt` and `actcattaat` even if either of those had a line break in between, ie. goes from the end of one line, line break plus line number plus space, and then continued on the next line?

Comment: @CBroe Yes that's exactly what I need!

Comment: Well then you would need to allow for a possible occurrence of newline character and the rest (line number and following space character) after _every single_ character in those words – and that would mean you could not use those assertions any more, because those have to be of fixed length (at least in a PCRE compatible regex engine AFAIK.)

Comment: @CBroe I see. What about this workaround: I make each sequence one separate line without the linebreaks. I could manage this in Python. Then my  (?<=tttcgt).*?(?=actcattaat) would be sufficient, woudn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you could remove all the line break, number and space beforehand, that would certainly make things easier. Maybe a search&replace operation first, that makes everything from one `>` character to the next into one line. If you liked to at least retain the first “initial” line number, the one that the `>` was on, that would also be easy enough to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your regex dot match `.*` include newlines, you need to specify the [`s` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers). Modifier depends on the implementation of regex.

In python it's the [`DOTALL` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL).

You can't regex a non-consecutive capture group (with characters missing from between input), but you can concat the two capture groups later on, or just string replace the sequence to be removed with an empty string.

Example:

```
import re;

data = """>M00707:15:000000000-AEN4L:1:1101:13198:1037_PairEnd_SUB_SUB merged_sample={14.3: 1}; count=1;       2:N:0:1
ctcccggaaaaatttgagcctccagagtagcatataaccgacacgttgccgcctgaaaat
acattttccaggtcttnnnnnaaannnggaagcgcgcaccgacgagctttnnannacaag
tgtggctctagtgctcggtatttgcaactttttaagtannatgnnngtcgnnnnngaggn
nnnnnnnnntaaccnnncaccttcaagcaagtctaagttctcgactaatcaaactataaa
tccgctacacggacccagatctcccgccncgtgcannttaaagcaagtctacgttattga
agatagaaactattatatcgctaaacgtagctctganncacgctcgccttgactccgact
ctgtcaatgtctacgaccaattgaggtggaacatgtgcacatgtgtttcagancattgga
ggaattccgggaaaataaattgaggcacaancgaacggtgatctnnnnnnnttagattct
gccatgttttttggcacgaacacaattgggcaaatactgttgggatgtggatggat
>M00707:15:000000000-AEN4L:1:1101:10949:1045_PairEnd_SUB_SUB_CMP merged_sample={13.3: 1}; count=1;       2:N:0:1
atgacatattaatgattcagcccacattccttaatataccacatatgacttacttttcta
tatcaacnnnnnnntactttccacaggtatatacatactatgtttaatactcattaattt
acttgncactatattattacattatatgattaatccacatttctataacatattagactt
tcctcaactagatattat(first)tttcgt(first)aattattatgcagttgtatgacatattactgaatca
gccaacattccttaataaaccncatacgactactctgttatcgtatgtgttttatggtct
tgattcttagtaatgggtatgacatattattgattcagccnnnattgttnannannnnac
atnnancttactnntcttnttcaactctaatatactttccacaggtatatacatactatg
ttnaat(last)actcattaat(last)ttacttgccaatatatcattnnnntatatgattaatccacattt
ctataacatattagactttcctcaactagatattattttcgtaattattatgcag"""

output = re.sub(r'(tttcgt).*(actcattaat)', r'\1\2', data, 0, flags=re.DOTALL)
print output
```

EDIT: made the code preserve the starting and ending sequences instead of removing them from output.